# in which file can control total price on magento2

Tags: magento2, model

we want to do a dev like the following image:
[image]

if the product is 1th-100th , each price of the product is 190€
if the product is 101th-150th , each price of the product is 250€
if the product is 151th-175th , each price of the product is 500€
if the product is 176th-200th , each price of the product is 1000€

the max-stock is: 200 , and if customer want to buy 120 products
the current total price should be:  20*190 + 50*250 + 25*500 + 25*1000 = 53800
and the unit price should be: 53800/120 = 448.3333333 ≈ 448.33

after doing the dev on **Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\Subtotal.php  protected function _initItem($address, $item)**
the unit price is ok , but the total price still not ok , it becomes to 448.33*120=53799.60 , **right algorithm should be :
20*190 + 50*250 + 25*500 + 25*1000 = 53800**

[image]

but i can't find the file which to change this functionality , is any one can help me?

thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

In magento2 for your requirement you need to do following things in your custom extensions,

Put overide Price.php into using extension di.xml file.

```
app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\di.xml
```

put code in di.xml file.

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price" type="Vendor\Extension\Model\Product\Type\Price"/>
```

Create a Price.php file in above define location and try to apply your logic in  `public function getFinalPrice()` this function.

Comment: If above answer help you then please accept, So it help other in community as well.

Comment: hello Dhiren, i konw what you are talking about , it's model overwrite. But the problem is on shoping cart , on quote. it's a wrong total price. public function getFinalPrice() is not useful. do you konw in which file and change the total price?

Comment: public function getFinalPrice() which calculate final price of the item, I already used this one. For your info set any static price here and then check your cart, so you get idea.

Comment: after checking , i found the function getFinalPrice() can set the unit price. but the problem is not unit price. it's the algorithm of the total price: 20*190 + 50*250 + 25*500 + 25*1000 = 53800. not qty x unit price.  qty x unit price === qty x getFinalPrice()

Comment: If you set proper unit price then it autometically calculate final price. For Debug set static unit price and then check. If you set unit price suppose 200 and added qty 200 then it show 200 X 200 = 40000. Hope you understand.